# Can not @autowired repository. Bean circular reference

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My `ApiConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(JpaProperties.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.foo.api.persistence")
@ComponentScan("com.foo.api")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yaml")
public class ApiConfig {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();
private static final String MODEL_PACKAGE = "com.foo.api.model";

@Autowired
private MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl multiTenantConnectionProvider;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Resource
private org.springframework.core.env.Environment env;

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverException {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(MODEL_PACKAGE);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);

    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);
    jpaProperties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProvider);
    jpaProperties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, getCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver());
    jpaProperties.put(Environment.DIALECT, getHibernateDialect());

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

private CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver getCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver() throws CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverException {
    CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver resolver = applicationContext.getBean(CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver.class);
    if (resolver == null) {
        throw new CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverException();
    }

    return resolver;
}

private String getHibernateDialect() {
    return env.getProperty(PropertyConstants.DIALECT);
}
```

}

But now i can not `@Autowired` my `JpaRepository`:

```
    @Autowired
    private AgreementPersistence agreementPersistence;
```

Agreement persistence is simple repo extends from JpaRepository with one own query based method;

**Exception log:**

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 

Could not autowire field: AgreementPersistence agreementPersistence; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 

Error creating bean with name 'agreementPersistence': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#38830ea' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 

Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#38830ea': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 

Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

How to fix it? 
Maybe i can set some bean creation order or something else?

**Also:**
I need to @Autowired repo in config class of another module.

Comment: Please add the Spring initialization error stack to your question so that it is more clear what I'd going wrong with the `@Autowired ` injection.

Comment: try calling the entityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet() method

Comment: It looks like you're trying to autowire `AgreementPersistence` into a class that's responsible for configuring JPA. Can you share more details of your `@Configuration` classes?

Comment: where do i need to call it?

Comment: Add full ApiConfig.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case i use two java configuration class in two different module.
In first i write custom entity manager factory bean, in another i try to autowired my own persistence extend JpaRepository.
In second configuration class i create own config bean where i use autowired repo. So i had unresolvable circular reference.

I work with it by adding repository argument in my config bean like this:

```
@Bean
Foo foo(RepoThatIWantToAutowired repo) { ... }
```

Maybe it could help for someone.

Answer (score 3):

A circular reference is when you have two beans, each injected into the other.

```
@Service
public class A {
    @Inject
    private B b;
}

@Service
public class B {
    @Inject
    private A a;
}
```

Since Spring can't inject something that is not completely instantiated, it can't inject `A` into `B` before `B` is injected into `A`, and vice versa, thus making Spring stuck.

In these situations you should first analyse, and see if there really is a need for a circular dependency. Perhaps decomposing the beans into something like this is what you really need:

```
@Service
public class C {
    @Inject
    private A a;
    @Inject
    private B b;
}
```

If you can't decompose your way out of it, this is one way of resolving the issue:

```
@Service
public class A {
    @Inject
    private B b;
}

@Service
public class B extends ApplicationContextAware {
    //no inject
    private A a;

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void handleDependencies() {
        this.a = applicationContext.getBean(A.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I still have same problem.
I have conf1 in module1(component scan "com.foo.mod1" where i init entityManagerFactoryBean;

Also I have conf2 in module2(component scan "com.foo.mod2";
Module2 compile dependencie to module1 in build.gradle;

In conf2 I @Import(Conf1.class);
But when i tried to get bean from appCtx, i have the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `@Lazy` to `entityManagerFactory` or `AgreementPersistence` (class that spring is complaining about not being able to inject).

I believe it will prevent spring to actually trying to inject "spring-configured" bean up until it is actually required. It should inject raw class first to satisfy dependency and spring-configured later.

Answer (score 0):

You are eventually initializing your JPA repositories multiple times. Try this:

```
 @ComponentScan(
    value = "com.foo.api",
    excludeFilters ={
            //@Repository beans are scanned and created by @EnableJpaRepositories already
            @ComponentScan.Filter(Repository.class)
    }
```

)

Comment: It does not help;
I think i get problem when spring try to autowired repo with inner bean EntityManager, when EntityManagerFactory is in creation;